# Formatting ChartLabels for a BarChart with ErrorBars

Tags: legending, labeling, charts

I have the following `BarChart`, that uses a custom ErrorBar function to plot error bars:

```
errorBar[type_: "Rectangle"][{{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}}, value_, 
  meta_] := 
 Block[{error, mags = QuantityMagnitude[value]}, 
  error = Flatten[QuantityMagnitude[meta]];
  error = 
   If[error === {}, 0, 
    Last[error]]; {ChartElementData[type][{{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}, mags, 
    meta], {Black, Thick, 
    Line[{{{(x0 + x1)/2, y1 - error}, {(x0 + x1)/2, 
        y1 + error}}, {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), 
        y1 + error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), 
        y1 + error}}, {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), 
        y1 - error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), y1 - error}}}]}}]
BarChart[{{-0.08` -> 0.07`, -0.06` -> 0.07`}, {0.27` -> 0.08`, 
   0.12` -> 0.08`}}, ChartLegends -> {{"A", "B"}, None}, 
 ChartLabels -> {{"Group 1", "Group 2"}, None}, 
 ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", None}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> errorBar["Rectangle"]]
```

[image]

As can be seen in the picture, the ChartLabels are plotted directly under the bars, but the error bars overlap. The ChartLabel function does not consider the length of the error bars.

I have the following question:

How can I adjust the distance between the ChartLabels and the error bars? In other words, I want the labels "Group 1", "Group 2" (and the associated lines) to be below the end of the error bars of "Group 1" and not the bars themselves (basically at the position where the y-axes ends).

Comment: Add `AxesOrigin -> {0, -0.2}` in `BarChart`

Comment: Well, that was easy and works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to keep the axes origin at `{0, 0}`, you can post-process the `BarChart` output to move the labels lower:

```
data = {{-0.08 -> 0.07, -0.06 -> 0.03}, {0.27 -> 0.08, 0.12 -> 0.05}};

bc1 = BarChart[data, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    ChartLegends -> {{"A", "B"}, None}, 
    ChartLabels -> {Style[#, 16] & /@ {"Group 1", "Group 2"},  None}, 
    ChartStyle -> {"Pastel", None}, 
    ChartElementFunction -> errorBar["Rectangle"]];

bc1 /. Text[t_, Offset[o_, {a_, b_}], c___] :>  Text[t, Offset[o, {a, -.17}], c]
```

[image]

If you have version 12, you can modify input data (replace `Rule` with [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html)) to create a chart with error bars without the need for a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
data2 = data /. Rule -> Around;
bc2 = BarChart[data2, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    ChartLegends -> {{"A", "B"}, None}, 
    ChartLabels -> {Style[#, 16] & /@ {"Group 1", "Group 2"}, None}, 
    ChartStyle -> { "Pastel", None}, 
    IntervalMarkers -> "Fences", 
    IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"FenceWidth" -> 0.2, 
        "WhiskerStyle" -> Thick,  "FenceStyle" -> Thick|>] ;

bc2 /.  Text[t_, Offset[o_, {a_, b_}], c___] :>  Text[t, Offset[o, {a, -.17}], c]
```

[image]